# Loop over matrix and choose row depending on variable number - R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a combination matrix which consists of five variables (A,B,C,D,E), each with five possible values, providing a total of 3125 possible combinations. A smaller incomplete example is below for two variables and five values (i.e. a 25 combination matrix)?

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A1 | B2 |
| A1 | B3 |
| A1 | B4 |
| A1 | B5 |
| A2 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A2 | B3 |
| A2 | B4 |
| A2 | B5 |
| A3 | B1 |

and so the complete table would have 25 different rows of each combination.

I am running 3125 forecasts and for each run (let's call it FCST_NUM) I would like to assign each variable (i.e. A,B,C,D,E) to a row in the matrix. So in forecast one (i.e. FCST_NUM=1) variables A,B,C,D,E use the values in the first row of the matrix, in forecast two (i.e. FCST_NUM=2) variables A,B,C,D,E use the values of the second row and so on.

In the code FCST_NUM would start from 1 and I would add 1 for each iteration. How could I define variables A,B,C,D,E so that each get assigned to the correct value in the row of the matrix based on the FCST_NUM (e.g. when FCST_NUM = X, values A,B,C,D,E is equal to row(,X) of matrix).

R code to produce matrix example is below:

```
N   <- 5 
vec <- c(0.2,0.6,1,1.4,1.8)
lst <- lapply(numeric(N), function(x) vec)
Matrix <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lst))
```

Comment: Do you have some code? What is your question? You did not ask any question.

Comment: I still do not understand the goal. What does the R code actually do? What kind of data structure do you want to get? An array? Or a derived type? There is no matrix type in Fortran.

Comment: Apologies for it not being clear, it's quite difficult to explain. I'm just trying to get an idea of how to assign values in the matrix to variables  dependent on the FCST_NUM.

Comment: What is wrong with 5 deep nested loops? Generalising to N deep is a little harder, but if you know the value of the nesting it's pretty straight forward

Comment: I'm assuming the question is how to code up the above in Fortran, for which, if I have it correct, simply a 5 deep loop nest is the natural and most simple solution. But yes, it should be clarified that that is what is wanted.

Comment: Yes, Fortran, but if not possible then R so I can visualise how it would work. Currently looking into nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually easier than I thought in R. It was just a case of setting FCST_NUM to whatever the number of the run was and then indexing from the matrix as below.

```
# create matrix of possible combinations 
N   <- 5 
vec <- c(0.2,0.6,1,1.4,1.8)
lst <- lapply(numeric(N), function(x) vec)
Matrix <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lst))

# define FCST_NUM
FCST_NUM = 1  

# assign value to each variable based on FCST_NUM
A <- Matrix[FCST_NUM,1]
B <- Matrix[FCST_NUM,2]
C <- Matrix[FCST_NUM,3]
D <- Matrix[FCST_NUM,4]
E <- Matrix[FCST_NUM,5]
```

So if FCST_NUM was 1, then variables A,B,C,D,E would be assigned to the    values on the 1st row of the matrix.